# The Vscode size and its icons and text have been reduced, what should I do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see below, my program does not have its actual size and is very small. please guide me.
Be sure to confirm the answer that helped me.

[image]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have zoomed? To reset the zoom level to default values use (Ctrl+Numpad0)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility